# Python : upload picture without disturbing normal flow of a program

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, detection, python-multithreading

In my code I am constantly grabbing frames from a camera to check if there is any human body present or not. whenever there is a human, crop the body and upload it on server. and keep doing this.
**PROBLEM:** Whenever I start a thread to upload photo to server my program execution stops and wait for the upload thread to finish. I don't want my program execution to stop and wait. I want it to run without stopping. I want to start a separate thread to upload photo that runs parallel, does its job without disturbing normal flow and finishes after it. it should do this every time there is a body detected.

```
# USAGE
# python detect.py --images images
# import the necessary packages
from __future__ import print_function
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
from imutils import paths
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import time
import threading
import Queue
import multiprocessing
import requests
from poster.encode import multipart_encode
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers
import urllib2
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
import Queue
import urllib
import traceback

size = 2
i=0
#Queues to store data
queue_FACES = multiprocessing.Queue()

(im_width, im_height) = (112, 112)

# initialize the HOG descriptor/person detector
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())

# Capture Camera Stream
#webcam = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/irum/Desktop/WIN_20170529_09_53_13_Pro.mp4')
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#h=4.27 w=4.29  AVG = 4.28

# Upload to server
def upload_internet(filename2,sampleFile,check_path1):

    #print("upoading....")
    filename2 = filename2+'.jpg'
    #print (filename2)      

    register_openers()

    datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"sampleFile": open(sampleFile), "name": filename2})
    #request = urllib2.Request("http://videoupload.hopto.org:5000/api/Sync_log", datagen, headers)
    request = urllib2.Request("http://videoupload.hopto.org:5002/api/Synclog", datagen, headers)

    try:
        #print ("***UPLOAD SERVER RESPONSE***")
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        html=response.read() 
        print ("html ",html)

        #resp = json.loads(html) 
        # with open('output_file.txt', "wb") as code: #CHANGE PATH
        #   code.write(curr_time+"\n"+html +"\n")

    except URLError , e:

        if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
            #print ('We failed to reach a server.')
            print ('Reason: ', e.reason)
        elif hasattr(e, 'code'):
            #print ('The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.')
            print ('Error code: ', e.code)

    except Exception:
        print ('generic exception: ' + traceback.format_exc())

while True:
    # read each frame
    ret, frame = webcam.read()
    # resize it
    image = imutils.resize(frame, width=min(300, frame.shape[1]))
    orig = image.copy()

    # detect people in the frame
    (rects, weights) = hog.detectMultiScale(image, winStride=(4, 4),
        padding=(8, 8), scale=1.05)

    # draw the original bounding boxes
    for i in range(len(rects)):

        body_i = rects[i]
        (x, y, w, h) = [v * 1 for v in body_i]
        cv2.rectangle(orig, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # apply non-maxima suppression
        rects = np.array([[x, y, x + w, y + h] for (x, y, w, h) in rects])
        pick = non_max_suppression(rects, probs=None, overlapThresh=0.65)

        # draw the final bounding boxes
        for i in range(len(rects)):

            body_i = rects[i]
            (xA, yA, xB, yB) = [int(v * 1) for v in body_i]

            # rect on scaled image
            cv2.rectangle(image, (xA, yA), (xB, yB), (0, 255, 0), 2) 
            # rects to map on original frame
            (x1, y1, w1, h1) = [int(v * 4.28) for v in body_i]
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (w1, h1), (0, 45, 255), 2)

            # Crop body from Original frame
            body_big = frame[y1:y1+h1, x1:x1+w1]

            # Save body
            save_body_path = '/home/irum/Desktop/pedestrian-detection/BIG_BODY' 
            cur_date = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
            cur_time = (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
            new_pin =cur_date+"-"+cur_time
            filename1 = 'BIG'
            filename2 = str(filename1)+"-"+str(new_pin)  
            print ("filename2",filename2)  
            sampleFile = ('%s/%s.jpg' % (save_body_path, filename2))
            print ("sampleFile",sampleFile)
            cv2.imwrite('%s/%s.jpg' % (save_body_path, filename2), body_big)

            # upload body
            upload_process = threading.Thread(target=upload_internet(filename2,sampleFile,save_body_path))
            upload_process.start()


    # show the output images
    cv2.imshow("Before NMS", orig)
    cv2.imshow("After NMS", image)
    cv2.imshow("BIG BODY", frame)
    # cv2.imshow("FACE", body_big2)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Correction:

1. Use `cThread = threading.Thread( target= , args=() )` to define a
   new thread instance
2. Use `cThread.start()` to launch it, of course you don't have join since your process is continuous.

simplified code so I could test-run it at my end:

```
import time
import threading
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep

def upload_internet(filename,sampleFile,check_path):
    print ("//// WAITING FOR SERVER RESPONSE")
    time.sleep(3)
    print ("RECEIVED SERVER RESPONSE \\\\\\")

filename = "filename"
sampleFile = "sampleFile"
save_body_path = "save_body_path"
key = 1

while True:

    rects = range(0,10)
    # draw the original bounding boxes
    range_len_rects = range(len(rects))

    for i in range_len_rects:

        print("Main starts")

        rects = range(0,10)
        thread_list = []

        for i in range_len_rects:

            # upload body
            thread_list.append ( threading.Thread( target=upload_internet, args=( filename + "-" + str(i) ,sampleFile,save_body_path) ) )
            thread_list[i].start()

            print ("Exiting Launch Thread loop :"+ str(i) + "/" + str(range_len_rects[i]) )

        print("Main sleep for 10 seconds")
        time.sleep(10);
        if key == 27:
            break
```

PS: Remember the thread is not destroyed and you must ensure the `upload_internet()` doesn't stuck in memory for any reason, or you can control number of instance you have and set cap and manage zombie threads to avoid process crash and bad memory management

Comment: Thanks ! It is very helpful. Just one more thing as I am new to python. If I need to run two more threads one like upload thread and other one where I need to wait for the result returned by the thread and then do further execution on the returned value. how would I implement this thread class ?

Comment: First of all, if the message is the correct answer you should tag it as "ANSWER" and there will be green checkbox next to my reply.

Comment: You can use `queue`'s `put()` and `get()` to stand-by parent thread and wait for reply,  https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html , I personally prefer to use `pipe()` with `multiprocessing` for that purpose 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe

Comment: I would have excepted it as an answer , but my problem stays the same. but it is still helpful cause I am new to python and don't know much about threading. I hope you didn't mind :p